# Fedora installation breaks UEFI boot

Tags: fedora, boot, system-installation, dual-boot, uefi

I am having problems installing Fedora 21/22-alpha on brand new system and I am new to the EFI thing so I am running into issues. I installed Win7, booted in UEFI, installed in UEFI, at least I see an EFI partition so that's a good indication it is in EFI. Boot security is disabled so I am guessing that's not the issue here.

I created a livecd usb with the following command:

```
livecd-iso-to-disk --format --reset-mbr --efi Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-22_Alpha-3.iso  /dev/sdb1
```

When I boot the system, I can select how to boot the liveusb so I select to boot it with UEFI. I see some lines that quickly scroll by then the system hangs at: "Use The" from what I guess is "use the arrow keys to make your selection" menu. The system is unresponsive at this point (power/reset button). If it matters, the motherboard is an ASRock x99 extreme 11.

I will add that if I boot in legacy mode (i.e. select the normal USB, not the UEFI: USB boot mode from the boot selector) I can boot the liveusb and install Fedora just fine, but I cannot get Windows to boot again. "Invalid Signature" error from Grub, no matter what I do (yes I did make sure to use the same `/boot/efi`).

Does anyone have any ideas? I even tried repair-boot and that did not work. I am also under the impression that I need to boot the liveusb with UEFI to install fedora with UEFI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve your issue but if you are planning to make UEFI boot your daily usage, I'd advise trying to avoid it, if possible. UEFI is by design meant to provide vendor lock-in courtesy of Microsoft (e.g. having the complete boot chain signed with keys only Microsoft manages) and yields more [troubles than it solves](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA4NDA).